# Facebook Page Tabs position attribute stopped working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

According this [Facebook page tab documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/tabs) you can update the 'position' of the Tab by calling a http post as follows :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/{pageId}/tabs?access_token={pageToken}
```

*At this endpoint you can update a Page tab's position with the POST request, passing the parameter tab=TAB_NAME&position=TAB_POS.*

This has stopped working recently (perhaps since Facebook rolled out page templates for Admins).

I am able to update the custom_name and image for the tab. And I can also see the 'position' attribute for the tab is changed to the new value. However the actual position of the Tab on the page does not change. Earlier calling the above post, would actually move the tab within the list of other tabs.

I am looking for help on what is the new way to change the tab position.

Thanks.

Comment: Facebook have acknowledged this as a bug on their platform and are close to deploying a fix : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1302804313113666/

Answer (score 1):

Facebook have acknowledged this as a bug on their platform and are close to deploying a fix : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1302804313113666/